# UIPageViewControllerDataSource

Tags: ios, swift

Подскажите пожалуйста насчет методов

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

и

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

А именно интересует в какой момент они вызываются и что передается в них в качестве viewController?

Answer (score 1):

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

Возвращает следующий `UIViewController` после текущего или `nil`, если текущий `UIViewController` последний.

```
pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

соответственно, возвращает предыдущий `UIViewController` перед текущим или `nil`, если текущий `UIViewController` первый.

Являются обязательными. Необходимы они для навигации(переходу, перелистыванию) по Вашему набору `UIViewController`ов. Вызываются в момент, когда начинается переход с текущего на следующий/предыдущий `UIViewController`.